# How to construct a query that matches exactly a vector of refs in DataScript?

Tags: clojure, clojurescript, datomic, datalog, datascript

**Setup** Consider the following DataScript database of films and cast, with data stolen from [learndatalogtoday.org](http://www.learndatalogtoday.org): the following code can be executed in a JVM/Clojure REPL or a ClojureScript REPL, as long as `project.clj` contains `[datascript "0.15.0"]` as a dependency.

```
(ns user
  (:require [datascript.core :as d]))

(def data 
  [["First Blood" ["Sylvester Stallone" "Brian Dennehy" "Richard Crenna"]]
   ["Terminator 2: Judgment Day" ["Linda Hamilton" "Arnold Schwarzenegger" "Edward Furlong" "Robert Patrick"]]
   ["The Terminator" ["Arnold Schwarzenegger" "Linda Hamilton" "Michael Biehn"]]
   ["Rambo III" ["Richard Crenna" "Sylvester Stallone" "Marc de Jonge"]]
   ["Predator 2" ["Gary Busey" "Danny Glover" "Ruben Blades"]]
   ["Lethal Weapon" ["Gary Busey" "Mel Gibson" "Danny Glover"]]
   ["Lethal Weapon 2" ["Mel Gibson" "Joe Pesci" "Danny Glover"]]
   ["Lethal Weapon 3" ["Joe Pesci" "Danny Glover" "Mel Gibson"]]
   ["Alien" ["Tom Skerritt" "Veronica Cartwright" "Sigourney Weaver"]]
   ["Aliens" ["Carrie Henn" "Sigourney Weaver" "Michael Biehn"]]
   ["Die Hard" ["Alan Rickman" "Bruce Willis" "Alexander Godunov"]]
   ["Rambo: First Blood Part II" ["Richard Crenna" "Sylvester Stallone" "Charles Napier"]]
   ["Commando" ["Arnold Schwarzenegger" "Alyssa Milano" "Rae Dawn Chong"]]
   ["Mad Max 2" ["Bruce Spence" "Mel Gibson" "Michael Preston"]]
   ["Mad Max" ["Joanne Samuel" "Steve Bisley" "Mel Gibson"]]
   ["RoboCop" ["Nancy Allen" "Peter Weller" "Ronny Cox"]]
   ["Braveheart" ["Sophie Marceau" "Mel Gibson"]]
   ["Mad Max Beyond Thunderdome" ["Mel Gibson" "Tina Turner"]]
   ["Predator" ["Carl Weathers" "Elpidia Carrillo" "Arnold Schwarzenegger"]]
   ["Terminator 3: Rise of the Machines" ["Nick Stahl" "Arnold Schwarzenegger" "Claire Danes"]]])

(def conn (d/create-conn {:film/cast {:db/valueType :db.type/ref
                                      :db/cardinality :db.cardinality/many}
                          :film/name {:db/unique :db.unique/identity
                                      :db/cardinality :db.cardinality/one}
                          :actor/name {:db/unique :db.unique/identity
                                       :db/cardinality :db.cardinality/one}}))
(def all-datoms (mapcat (fn [[film actors]]
                          (into [{:film/name film}] 
                                (map #(hash-map :actor/name %) actors)))
                        data))
(def all-relations (mapv (fn [[film actors]]
                           {:db/id [:film/name film]
                            :film/cast (mapv #(vector :actor/name %) actors)}) data))

(d/transact! conn all-datoms)
(d/transact! conn all-relations)
```

**Description** In a nutshell, there are two kinds of entities in this database—films and actors (word intended to be ungendered)—and three kinds of datoms:

- film entity: `:film/name` (a unique string)
- film entity: `:film/cast` (multiple refs)
- actor entity: `:actor/name` (unique string)

**Question** I would like to construct a query which asks: which films have these `N` actors, *and these `N` actors alone*, appeared as the sole stars, for N>=2?

E.g., RoboCop starred Nancy Allen, Peter Weller, Ronny Cox, but *no* film starred solely the first two of these, Allen and Weller. Therefore, I would expect the following query to produce the empty set:

```
(d/q '[:find ?film-name
       :where
       [?film :film/name ?film-name]
       [?film :film/cast ?actor-1]
       [?film :film/cast ?actor-2]
       [?actor-1 :actor/name "Nancy Allen"]
       [?actor-2 :actor/name "Peter Weller"]]
     @conn)
; => #{["RoboCop"]}
```

However, the query is flawed because I don't know how to express that any matches should exclude any actors who are not Allen or Weller—again, I want to find the movies where only Allen and Weller have collaborated without any other actors, so I want to adapt the above query to produce the empty set. How can I adjust this query to enforce this requirement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because DataScript doesn't have negation (as of May 2016), I don't believe that's possible with one static query in 'pure' Datalog.

My way to go would be:

1. build the query programmatically to add the N clauses that state that the cast must contain the N actors
2. Add a predicate function which, given a movie, the database, and the set of actors ids, uses the EAVT index to find if each movie has an actor that is not in the set.

Here's a basic implementation

```
(defn only-those-actors? [db movie actors]
  (->> (datoms db :eavt movie :film/cast) seq
    (every? (fn [[_ _ actor]]
                (contains? actors actor)))
    ))

(defn find-movies-with-exact-cast [db actors-names]
  (let [actors (set (d/q '[:find [?actor ...] :in $ [?name ...] ?only-those-actors :where
                           [?actor :actor/name ?name]]
                      db actors-names))
        query {:find '[[?movie ...]]
               :in '[$ ?actors ?db]
               :where
               (concat
                 (for [actor actors]
                   ['?movie :film/cast actor])
                 [['(only-those-actors? ?db ?movie ?actors)]])}]
    (d/q query db actors db only-those-actors?)))
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay (and sorry for bugging you on slack)! Is there any benefit to putting a check like `only-those-actors?` *in* the query? Versus just getting all the hits and post-processing outside the query, per https://gist.github.com/fasiha/647a48420770536a4fa952a4b38f69d7#file-stackoverflow-clj-L97-L116 ? Would this implementation suffer by not going the `datoms` route?

Comment: You implementation seems fine too! You make a clever use of distinct. As an optimization, maybe you can just  count the number of distinct actors, which is more efficient than sorting. About whether or not to use datoms: I won't make any claims about performance, you should run benchmarks.

Comment: I had to clean up one or two additional things in the code as it is currently: https://gist.github.com/fasiha/647a48420770536a4fa952a4b38f69d7#file-stackoverflow-clj-L60-L85 (in case you want to update the answer) but it works! Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use predicate fun and `d/entity` together for filtering datoms by `:film/cast` field of an entity. This approach looks much more straightforward until Datascript doesn't support negation (**not** operator and so on).

Look at the row `(= a (:age (d/entity db e))` in the test case of the Datascript [here](https://github.com/tonsky/datascript/blob/c99b40ada69458f16f4a46ae5ffdf8787dbda32d/test/datascript/test/query_fns.cljc#L252-L259)

```
[{:db/id 1 :name "Ivan" :age 10}
 {:db/id 2 :name "Ivan" :age 20}
 {:db/id 3 :name "Oleg" :age 10}
 {:db/id 4 :name "Oleg" :age 20}]

...

(let [pred (fn [db e a]
             (= a (:age (d/entity db e))))]
  (is (= (q/q '[:find ?e
                :in $ ?pred
                :where [?e :age ?a]
                       [(?pred $ ?e 10)]]
              db pred)
         #{[1] [3]})))))
```

In your case, the predicate body could look something like this

```
(clojure.set/subset? actors (:film/cast (d/entity db e))
```

In regards to performance, the `d/entity` call is fast because it is a lookup by index.